# Maven Dependencies in SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

This is my first time using Maven and for some reason on my machine I am unable to get two of the hibernate dependencies that I need. My Pom.xml file is below:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>com.aramburu</groupId>
                <artifactId>depcheck</artifactId>
                <name>depcheck</name>
                <packaging>war</packaging>
                <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <properties>
                    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
                    <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
                    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
                    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
                </properties>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Spring -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                             </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- AspectJ -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>   

                    <!-- Logging -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.15</version>
                        <exclusions>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                            <exclusion>
                                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                            </exclusion>
                        </exclusions>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- @Inject -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                        <version>1</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Servlet -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                        <scope>provided</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Test -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>4.7</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.8.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.9</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <additionalProjectnatures>
                                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                                </additionalProjectnatures>
                                <additionalBuildcommands>
                                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                                </additionalBuildcommands>
                                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3.2</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>1.6</source>
                                <target>1.6</target>
                                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

                <dependencyManagement>

                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                            <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </dependencyManagement>
            </project>
```

For some reason org.hibernate hibernate-entitymanager

cannot be found. The maven setup I am using is the default that comes with springsource tool suite. I made no modifications to the version of maven they gave me. I am trying to build this on 64 bit windows machine with jdk 7 installed.

I have looked into the other solutions like updating depdencies and configuration in the menu that pops up when you right click on a project and go to maven.

Some people have said I need to enable the dependencies but there is no menu to do so on the right and I am able to download things like the hibernate core and have the dependencies be properly resolved. Just having issues with that specific dependency.

Do I need to add repositories or anything of that nature to the original settings.xml file provided with the installation of maven in SpringSource Tool Suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This dependency seems to be not found on your default repository maven is looking into, It exist at [jboss's maven repository](http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2/)

So to enable maven to look for that repository too add following into your `pom.xml`

```
<project ...>
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>JBoss repository</id>
      <url>http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
</project>
```

And try `mvn clean install`

Comment: i responded to your comment by editing but i get an error using this do I need to add a pom.xml to my maven installation?

Comment: each maven project has a pom.xml file, You need to add this configuration in it

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Maven from console, you need to do it in a directory with your pom.xml file.

For Hibernate stuff, you possibly need to declare the following in your pom.xml (or settings.xml):

```
    <repository>
        <id>repository.jboss.org</id>
        <name>JBoss Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

central Maven Repository Switchboard default http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 false com.springsource.repository.libraries.release SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release